# onMOuseOver onMouseOut not working embeded with php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am selecting two image from database and want to show them `onMOuseOver` and `onMouseOut`.

Here is my code:

```
<img onmouseover="this.src=' .$him[0]. '" onmouseout="this.src='.$image_full[0].'" src="'.$image_full[0].'"  />
```

Comment: please provide your php code too.

make sure that your $image_full[0] is not null

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512449/how-to-change-image-with-onmouseover-in-different-place-that-reverts-back-to-def

Comment: I have tested both image are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you like php print html code or html print php code, in both cases, be carefull with ' and ":

PHP print html code:

```
echo '<img onmouseover="this.src=\'' .$him[0]. '\'" onmouseout="this.src=\''.$image_full[0].'\'" src="'.$image_full[0].'"  />';
```

HTML print PHP code:

```
<img onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $him[0] ?>'" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $image_full[0] ?>'" src="'<?php echo $image_full[0] ?>'"  />
```

If you try html print php code, you need to save your html code as php code

Answer (score 0):

Could be the single quotatation marks in the 'src' property. Seems like they shouldn't be there, only for the javascript events because there's a string inside a string.

Without the extra single quotation marks it seems to work just fine for me.

Example:

```html
<img
  onmouseover="this.src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/AndalusQuran.JPG/94px-AndalusQuran.JPG'"
  onmouseout="this.src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cc/Nacreous_clouds_Antarctica.jpg/110px-Nacreous_clouds_Antarctica.jpg'"
  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/140626_Tierser_Alpl_Rossz%C3%A4hne.jpg/245px-140626_Tierser_Alpl_Rossz%C3%A4hne.jpg"
/>
```